# CSS/HTML variable container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that has varying cells of varying widths that are hiding/showing based on user toggle. I would like the container div to expand with the columns.

I was thinking of looping through a `$('.row').first().find('.cell')` and calculating/tallying the width and setting the `#container` width like that, but was hoping for a better solution to come along.

On a sidenote, since the `.cell` divs are `float: left`, would I want to specify a height for my `.row` or use `display: inline-block`?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sm-cell cell cell-1">1</div>
    <div class="md-cell cell cell-2">2</div>
    <div class="sm-cell cell cell-3">3</div>
    <div class="sm-cell cell cell-4">4</div>
    <div class="sm-cell cell cell-5">5</div>
    <div class="md-cell cell cell-6">6</div>
    <div class="lg-cell cell cell-7">7</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear { clear: both; }

.row {
    margin: 1px 0;
}

.cell {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: #999999;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

**Interactive jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/uenz4hee/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `display:table`

```
#container {
    display:table;
    background: #DEDEDE;
}


.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: #999999;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/uenz4hee/12/)

Also means you can get rid of your clear divs

**UPDATE**

If you want the cells not to wrap when the screen size is too small you can use `display:inline-block` instead:

```
#container {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #DEDEDE;
}

.row {
    margin: 1px 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0; /* this is to stop the space between cells */
}

.cell {
    font-size:10px; /* this should be set to your original font-size */
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: #999999;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/uenz4hee/20/)

If you don't want to use the font-size hack, you will need to comment out the white-space between your `div.cell`

Comment: This works fairly well! Thanks for the response!

The only caveat is that it seems to squish everything to fit the current viewport instead of extending beyond it.

Also, would you happen to know if this invokes any sort of overhead when switching to this kind of display? Our current page uses tables and render time is ludicrous.

Comment: Not sure about the performance, didn't realise table-cells would wrap - that's very interesting.  I'll see if I can find a work around

Comment: Perfect! I knew there was a combination of hacks I was totally missing out on. Thanks for saving me a week of flubbing around.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with an `inline-block` display for each cell:

```
.cell {
  display:inline-block; /* <--- */
  text-align: center;
  background: #999999;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

So it behaves like text, and set the row as `nowrap`, avoiding to break its contents in new lines, and instead expanding the containing div accordig to it:

```
.row {
  margin: 1px 0;
  white-space: nowrap; /* <--- */
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ofejh58/1/

Comment: For completeness, an alternative to `white-space:nowrap` for old browsers is the tag `<nobr></nobr>` (http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/nobr)